# jQuery list hiding/showing not working in Play framework but working in regular HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scala, playframework

I am trying to get a list to show 3 items then the user can click on "Load More" to show more items. I stripped out the Scala bits to make it into plain HTML in JS Fiddle and everything works as expected there. When I work with the code in my IDE and make it into Scala template with a for loop and such, the code compiles, but the list shows nothing. I know my routing is fine since the CSS and Material Design parts work. It's just this one block that is behaving in a way I wasn't expecting.

Here are the code pieces:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    size_li = $("#skills-list li").size();
    showingItems = 3;
    $('#skills-list li:lt(' + showingItems + ')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function() {
        showingItems = (showingItems + 5 <= size_li) ? showingItems + 5 : size_li;
        $('#skills-list li:lt(' + showingItems + ')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function() {
        showingItems = (showingItems - 5 < 0) ? 3 : showingItems - 5;
        $('#skills-list li').not(':lt(' + showingItems + ')').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
#skills-list li {
  display:none;
}

#loadMore {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#loadMore:hover {
  color: black;
}

#showLess {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#showLess:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="section--center mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing">
      <h4 class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">Skills</h4>
      <div class="section__circle-container mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--1-col-phone">
        <div class="section__circle-container__circle mdl-color--primary"><img src="@routes.Assets.versioned(" images/icons/skills.svg ")" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="section__text mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col-desktop mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone">
        @if(profile.skills.isEmpty()) {
        <span>
                                Add some skills</span> } else {
        <ul class="mdl-list" id="skills-list">
          @for(extractedHardSkill
          <- profile.skills) { <li class="mdl-list__item" id="skill-item">
            <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">@skill.name</span>
            </li>
            }
        </ul>
        }
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions">
        <div id="loadMore" class="mdl-button">Load more</div>
        <div id="showLess" class="mdl-button">Show less</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: `@skill.name` does not make sense, since the variable in your for loop is named `extractedHardSkill`. That line break inside the for loop definition seems very suspicious too, I don't think the template compiler can deal with that. I'd be surprised if this compiles... It's also not a good idea to make multiple list items with the same ID, use a class for that instead.

Comment: After testing it, it seems the split line for loop definition works fine. Still wondering how the compiler does not trip over the `@skill.name` part though, which is hard to reproduce based on this information.

Comment: try to remove  id="skill-item". It is used in for loop while id should be unique